# onFinishInflate not being called when dynamically instantiating and adding a compound control

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a custom control which serves as a base to other compound controls (BaseControl) which inherits RelativeLayout.
This BaseControl is intended to simplify inflating the XML on each control and initialize them after that. Everything is done in the constructor:

```
abstract class BaseControl extends RelativeLayout {

    public BaseControl(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.baseInitializeControl(context, null);
    }

    public BaseControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.baseInitializeControl(context, attrs);
    }

    public BaseControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.baseInitializeControl(context, attrs);
    }

    private void baseInitializeControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        int layoutId = this.getControlLayoutId();
        if(layoutId != 0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            inflater.inflate(layoutId, this);
        }

        this.initializeControl(context, attrs);
    }

    protected abstract int getControlLayoutId();
    protected abstract void initializeControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
}
```

The actual problem is that I set the OnItemClickedListener to a control's internal ListView but it doesn't respond to any click, problem which I didn't have before I abstracted the BaseControl class. I got this problem solved calling the ListView's setOnItemClickedListener method in onFinishInflate.

So I have CustomList1 and CustomList2, both inherit BaseControl.
On CustomList1 I have:

```
@Override
protected int getControlLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.custom_list_1;
}

@Override
protected void initializeControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this.mListView = this.findTypedViewById(R.id.listView);

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext());
    this.mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    this.mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
            HistoryGroupList.this.onListItemClicked(parentView, childView, position, id);
        }
    });
}

private void onListItemClicked(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
    CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) this.mListView.getAdapter();
    CustomData data = adapter.getItem(position);

    CustomList2 list = new CustomList2(getContext(), data); // CustomList2 should query more data here.

    this.addView(list); // The new View is added in front of the current one
}
```

So far so good, the first CustomList responds to the item clicked, creates a new control (with a second list view in it) and shows it in the front.

The second control (CustomList2) is almos the same code, it only returns a different id in getControlLayoutId(), shows a Toast in onListItemClicked(...) and it uses the second parameter of its constructor to create a different adapter.
The problem is that this second control isn't executing onFinishInflate(), event though that it is inflating an xml in the BaseControl.
If I add this control as an XML tag into another layout then the onFinishInflate() method is executed normally.

Do you know why this method isn't being executed? or maybe a workaround to solve the problem with the setOnItemClickedListener method.

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try calling super.onFinishInflate() after you create the listener. It seems odd but I've noticed from past experience, sometimes the method terminates after the super call.

```java
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    this.mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {
            HistoryGroupList.this.onListItemClicked(parentView, childView, position, id);
        }
    });

    super.onFinishInflate();    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem just put `setOnItemClickListener` after call of `Inflate` (works fine for me).